# ng serve not working inside an angular project folder using CMD in Windows

Tags: angular

I am trying to run `ng serve`  in `Windows 10` environment inside my angular project but it returns the error listed below:

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am inside below folder

> C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\npm\angular-hello-world>ng serve

What am I doing wrong here.

I am a newbie so easy clear steps would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: try `npm start` or install it globally like `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Why are you running inside AppData?

Comment: WHere should i run this from?

Comment: THank you that worked. @smnbbrv

Comment: @LucyJones posted it as an answer so you can accept it :)

Comment: @LucyJones, AppData is a hidden folder meant to store software settings, i.e. globally installed npm packages, and such. It's not a directory I recommend using for development purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is just not installed globally.

Try `npm start` to go on without global installation or simply install it globally: `npm install -g @angular/cli`